# Implementing an ADT to describe finite sets

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that implements an ADT to describe finite sets. It will extend an `ArrayUnboundedList` from our text book.  One of the methods that are to be included is a "union" method.

The description for the method (as given by the professor) is:

```
public ArraySetList<T> union(SetListInterface<T> someSet) {
    //returns a new set consisting of all the elements in this or in someSet.  someSet and this
    //remain unchanged
}
```

So my question is how do I use "this" to refer to a set?

To take the union of 2 sets, you need 2 sets.  I am assuming that I am to use someSet as one of them and "this" as the other.  However, I am not very familiar with using this in java.

I understand what it is the method is supposed to do, I just need help with using the "this" as a set.

Comment: Is the `union` method inside `ArrayUnboundedList`? Then you can just use the `this` keyword, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `this` is a set and the param `someSet` is a set. The `union` method will construct a third set, a new instance of `ArraySetList` and copy the elements of `this` and the elements of the parameter `someSet` into the new `ArraySetList`, which it returns.